How to compile C# .NET Core app for Linux on a Windows machine
I'm new to C#, Visual Studio and .Net. I have a working machine running Windows 10 on which I write software (console app), and several test machines running different Unix systems. I need to compile an executable file written under VisualStudio to then run it under Unix. How can I achieve this if possible?
I tried building via
dotnet build Deser.csproj -r linux-64 -o D:\test

but the result is a set of files for Windows (.exe, etc.).
And im tried publish via
dotnet publish Deser.csproj -r linux-x64 -o D:\test -c Release

with output:  error MSB4803: The "GenerateBootstrapper" task is not supported in the MSBuild version of .NET Core. Use the MSBuild version of the .NET Framework.

dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64 --configuration Release

Thank you for the answer. Result - error MSB4803 with a "GenerateBootstrapper" task. Full text: error MSB4803: The "GenerateBootstrapper" task is not supported in the MSBuild version of .NET Core. Use the MSBuild version of the .NET Framework. More information: https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803.
Of the attempts to fix it, I only came across launching dotnet from VS Command Line - without success, since my version does not have it.

Which .NET Core version are you using? The oldest supported version is .NET 6. The current LTS version is 8, and direct to Docker publishing is available since 7. I just created a new Console project and published it with dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 without any problems. Post enough code so people can replicate the problem

NETCore.App defines versions 6.0.29 and 8.0.5. SDK version is 8.0.300. How to determine which one is picked up?

I downloaded the 2022 version of VS from scratch, created an empty consoleApplication project and tried to publish - the result did not change.
Perhaps it’s worth downloading the latest version of .Net Core separately and somehow linking it to VS? I apologize if this is so, but it seemed strange to me that the IDE for .NET comes without .Net Core included...
